# ImageBackground won't render react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm doing a project in react native and my ImageBackgroud component does not want to render. The odd thing is I am already using ImageBackground in another component and it works there. I tried resizing the image but that didn't help.

Here is my component that renders child component with ImageBackground:

```
const DuringStay = () => {

  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
             <FlatList
              data={test}
              numColumns={2}
              columnWrapperStyle={{
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                marginBottom: 15,
              }}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <DuringStayTile item={item} />
              )}
            /> 
        </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default DuringStay;
```

Here is my component that doesn't want to render ImageBackground. My data comes correctly to the component and inside Pressable i can render other components but ImageBackground won't show up

```
const DuringStayTile = ({item}) => {
  const { title, uri } = item;
  console.log(title,uri)
  return (
    <Pressable style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={uri} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
              <LinearGradient 
              style={styles.textBox}
              colors={['transparent','rgba(0,0,0,0.6)']}>
                <Text>
                  {title} 
                </Text>
              </LinearGradient>
        </ImageBackground>
    </Pressable>
  );
};

export default DuringStayTile;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '48%',
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding:60,
    backgroundColor:'pink'
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow:'hidden',
    justifyContent:'center'
  },
  textBox:{
    position:'absolute',
    right:0,
    bottom:0,
    width:'100%'

  },
});
```

Data that is imported:

```
 export const test = [
  {
      uri:require('../assets/f1.jpg'),
      title: 'Zip Line',
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba'
    },
    {
      uri: require('../assets/during.jpeg'),
      title: 'Blue Cave',
     id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    },
    {
      uri: require('../assets/post.jpg'),
      title: 'Rafting',
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow:'hidden',
    justifyContent:'center',
 padding:30
  },
```